# MS-Access Form shows Number, not Name on load

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I got a Database, where I apply to a name a Main and Subgroup.
When I enter a MainGroup f.e. Granades, just subgroup elements like "attack-granades" etc. should be shown.
In genereal it works by writing in this into the MainGroup-Combobox at my Form.

```
 Private Sub MunHauptgruppeRef_AfterUpdate()    
Me.MunUntergruppeRef.Requery
Me.MunUntergruppeRef.RowSource = " SELECT UnterGrpNR, UnterGrpName FROM tbl_UnterGruppen WHERE UnterHauptGruppenNr = " & MunHauptgruppeRef.Value & "   ORDER BY UnterGrpName ASC"
```

The Problem is, if I load the datas in my form again, it just shows the related Number to the "Sub-Combobox data" [1](http://i.epvpimg.com/N0ETdab.png)( f.e. 35 for Attack-Grenade ) , but not the Name itself. After I reselect the entry in my Main-Combobox(Grenade), it shows the right sub-data which was saved. [2](http://i.epvpimg.com/CmA3aab.png)

Tried Requery on Form_Load or Requery of the Combo-Boxes itself. nothing helped so far.

Made some Video[3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0Ytp_0hK6I&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Simply hide the first column of combo box (i.e., set first column width to 0 in Property Sheet)

Comment: already tied.... than the column is still blank. Thats the problem sir...

Comment: What is your desired result? For number and name to show?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0Ytp_0hK6I&feature=youtu.be added a video for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the code from `Private Sub MunHauptgruppeRef_AfterUpdate()` to your Form_Current event, this will refresh your combo box row source to the current value of your `MunHauptgruppeRef` combobox as you cycle through your records. Also you need to call the `Me.MunUntergruppeRef.Requery` after you've set the `Me.MunUntergruppeRef.RowSource`.

You can also add a check when your in a New Record, for the code not to run on the Current Event. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.newrecord

Comment: Thank you! It helped and worked like you said ! I appreciate your help.